# perl split to grab time in the string

Tags: perl, split

Current we have a shared software, the purpose of the script is to collect all the using time for each user. To do this, I want to find the log file by user and grab the rows which record the running time and add it up to a final number for each user.

1. The code is written in Perl.
2. I have all userid saved in one file say userlist
3. In a loop, for each userid to get all time related rows and saved in one variable.

   ```
   my $output = `find / -name "$userID" -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'running time' ` ;
   ```

The content in `$output` will be like following:

```
logPath:Time INFO  [XXX] :user -       running time           1.75 seconds
logPath:Time INFO  [XXX] :user -       running time           0.34 seconds
logPath:Time INFO  [XXX] :user -       running time           21.15 seconds
logPath:Time INFO  [XXX] :user -       running time           43:10.83
logPath:Time INFO  [XXX] :user -       running time           10:50.77
```

The question for me is that: how should I wrote the split function or use some other ways to sum up these times? 43:10.83 is 43 mins and 10.83 seconds.

Comment: `split` is best used when you have a fixed number of fields from line to line.  You don't here.  A regex is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $secs = 0;
while ($output =~ /running time\s+(?:(\d+):)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/g) {
    $secs += $1*60 if $1;
    $secs += $2;
}
```